# method with a generic type constraint, how to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8

I am using following method to save and get data from IsolatedStorageSettings"

Then let's provide two methods Save/Load:

```
public static void SaveAudioList(string AudioListKey, IList<SongPlay> audioList)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains(AudioListKey)) settings[AudioListKey] = audioList;
    else settings.Add(AudioListKey, audioList);
}
```

and I saved data like this:

```
SongPlay songdetail = new SongPlay();
//songdetail.Album = "1";
//songdetail.Artist = "Love Guru";
songdetail.SongName = (string)track["name"];
songdetail.Url =(string)track["url"];

AudioTracks.Add(songdetail);
//StorageUtility.AddOrUpdateValue("tracklist", AudioTracks);
ClassLib.Class1.SaveAudioList("id", AudioTracks);
```

And from get value I write the following method:

```
public static void LoadAudioList<T>(string AudioListKey, ref T target) where T : IList<SongPlay>
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (!settings.Contains(AudioListKey)) throw new NotImplementedException(); // do something - list doesnt exist
    target = (T)settings[AudioListKey];
}
```

Now I want to use this:

```
LoadAudioList
```

How can I call it?

Comment: Please put more effort into your questions in future - use full sentences, with proper capitalization, format your code nicely, and generally read through the whole thing before you post, asking yourself if that's the kind of question *you'd* want to help with.

Comment: In terms of *answering* your question - it's not really clear why you've got a generic method to start with... why is your method not just `IList<SongPlay> LoadAudioList(string key)`?

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `LoadAudioList` a generic method?
It's a void function that wants to perform a simple assignment of `IList<SongPlay>`.

Why not implement it something like this:

```
public static IList<SongPlay> LoadAudioList(string AudioListKey)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (!settings.Contains(AudioListKey)) throw new NotImplementedException(); // do something - list doesnt exist
    return settings[AudioListKey] as IList<SongPlay>;
}
```

If you want to keep it void:

```
public static void LoadAudioList(string AudioListKey, ref IList<SongPlay> target)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (!settings.Contains(AudioListKey)) throw new NotImplementedException(); // do something - list doesnt exist
    target = settings[AudioListKey] as IList<SongPlay>;
}
```